# Certificate passphrase - mitmproxy isn't reading it from config.yaml or from command line

Tags: mitmproxy, passphrase

Hello mitmproxy community,

I am trying to use a self signed certificate under mitmproxy. So I placed the pem file (containing the private key as well as the public key) in .mitmproxy folder and named if mitmproxy-ca.pem. By this way, when I run mitmproxy, it generates an on-the-fly certificate that's issued to the SSL domain I am visiting, based on my self signed certificate. Everything works well so far.

This certificate has a passphrase which I must type in whenever I rum mitmproxy. I was trying to see if it is possible to automate the startup - this requires the passphrase to be given either as config entry in config.yaml or as a command line argument to mitmproxy. I am noticing that both of these options does not work.

As per mitmproxy documentation:

```
cert_passphrase
Passphrase for decrypting the private key provided in the --cert option.
Default: None
```

However, if I give a command like this, it will still ask me for the passphrase, that too two times.

```
mitmproxy --certs *=mitmproxy-ca.pem --set cert_passphrase=abcd
```

Putting the certs entry as well as the cert_passphrase entry in config.yaml also doesn't help. It is reading the certs entry from the yaml file, but still asks for passphrase upon running the mitmproxy command.

Can anyone please throw some light into this? May be I am missing something.

Comment: I would assume that once there was a `--cert` option that has later been changed to `--certs`. The latter ignores the `cert_passphrase` option (just a guess). I would recommend to create a [bug report](https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/issues).

Comment: Thanks Robert! Filing a bug report on this then.